# How do I migrate my Android library's usage of the "maven-publish" and "signing" Gradle plugins from the Groovy DSL to the Kotlin DSL?

Tags: gradle, android-library, gradle-kotlin-dsl, maven-publish

I am using the [maven-publish](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) and [signing](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/signing_plugin.html) Gradle plugins in my Android library's Groovy DSL `build.gradle` file as follows:

```groovy
plugins {
    id("maven-publish")
    id("signing")
}

android {
    publishing {
        singleVariant("release") {
            withJavadocJar()
            withSourcesJar()
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        release(MavenPublication) {
            afterEvaluate {
                from components.release
            }

            groupId getProperty("groupId")
            artifactId getProperty("artifactId")
            version getProperty("version")
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/"
            credentials {
                username getProperty("sonatypeUsername")
                password getProperty("sonatypePassword")
            }
        }
    }
}

signing {
    sign publishing.publications.release
}
```

I have omitted the parts of my `build.gradle` file which are unrelated to or optional for publishing and signing.

How do I convert these declarations to the Kotlin DSL?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the declarations converted to the Kotlin DSL:

```kotlin
plugins {
    `maven-publish`
    signing
}

android {
    publishing {
        singleVariant("release") {
            withJavadocJar()
            withSourcesJar()
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("release") {
            afterEvaluate {
                from(components["release"])
            }

            groupId = properties["groupId"].toString()
            artifactId = properties["artifactId"].toString()
            version = properties["version"].toString()
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/")
            credentials {
                username = properties["sonatypeUsername"].toString()
                password = properties["sonatypePassword"].toString()
            }
        }
    }
}

signing {
    sign(publishing.publications["release"])
}
```

### Notes

1. The declarations above work for me with version 8.6 of Gradle and version 8.3 of the Android Gradle Plugin.
2. You can find a complete `build.gradle.kts` file which includes all of the declarations above [here](https://github.com/TazkiyaTech/android-test-utils/blob/master/library/build.gradle.kts).
3. The [Android Gradle Plugin > Publish your library](https://developer.android.com/build/publish-library) Android Developers documentation has Kotlin DSL examples for most of the declarations above.